# How to grep contents from list of files from Linux ls or find command

Tags: linux, grep, ls

I am running -> "find . -name '*.txt'" command and getting list of files.

I am getting below mention output:

```
./bsd/contrib/amd/ldap-id.txt
./bsd/contrib/expat/tests/benchmark/README.txt
./bsd/contrib/expat/tests/README.txt
./bsd/lib/libc/softfloat/README.txt
```

and so on,

Out of these files how can i run grep command and read contents and filter only those files which have certain keyword? for e.g. "version" in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xargs` is a great way to accomplish this, and its already been covered.

The `-exec` option of `find` is also useful for this. It will perform a command over all files returned from find.

To invoke `grep` as few times as possible, passing multiple filenames to each call:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -H 'foo' {} +
```

Alternately, to invoke `grep` exactly once for each file found:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -H 'foo' {} ';'
```

In either case, `{}` is like a placeholder for the values from `find`; if your shell is zsh, it may be necessary to escape it, as in `'{}'`.

Comment: I'd suggest the `-exec ... {} +` form of `find` to reuse a single `grep` instance across as many files as possible, just as `xargs` does. (This has been part of the POSIX spec for `find` since 2006; it's not just a GNUism).

Comment: That's interesting. I never knew about that. Could you edit the answer and add some explanation. I'm curious.

Comment: So `command {}` => `comand file1` while `command {} +` => `comand file1 file2 ...` ? Oh, I guess I can just RTFM. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Exactly. Since there's an operating-system limit on maximum combined length of command-line options and environment variables, more than one `grep` can be needed for a long list of files, but if it'll all fit into one command line, `{} +` will do it that way.

Comment: Right.. -exec, I couldn't remember the option in my answer.  It may be "old" by some measures, but I've been using unix variants since the mid 90s, and find/xargs without -exec dates back to that era or perhaps earlier.

Comment: `-exec {} \;` was most certainly widespread in the 90s, even though `-exec {} +` wasn't (yet).

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a function built into find for that, but to be portable across platforms, I typically use xargs.  Say you want to find all the xml files in or below the current directly and get a list of each occurrence of 'foo', you can do this:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 grep -H foo
```

It should be self-explanatory except for the `-print0`, which separates filenames with NULs rather than newlines, and the `-0`, which tells xargs to use those NULs rather than interpreting spaces and quotes as syntax (which can confuse it if filenames contain either).

Comment: Eh? `find -print0` / `xargs -0` isn't about avoiding hitting the maximum number of arguments; it's about correctly handling all possible filenames, including those with whitespace or literal newlines.

Comment: You're right of course, I don't know why I misremembered that about the print0/-0.  I use it out of habit after having to deal with files that had bad characters in their names.  The -n is there to handle the command line length.  Without it, you may have to also monkey around with -s.

Comment: Using a correct value of `ARG_MAX` out-of-the-box is part of xargs' job. If you need to monkey with either `-n` or `-s`, either your operating system's xargs implementation or the build system they used to put together the binary (if, for instance, the compile-time detection picked up headers that don't match the target OS) needs correcting. I'm not inclined to suggest that people use suboptimal solutions (`-n 1` is wildly inefficient) to make up for OS vendor failures.

Comment: I can't remember exactly when I started habitually using -n 1 with xargs.  It's certainly not needed on any modern system that I know of, but it's safe to use regardless of the state of the OS or it's age, with a performance penalty that may or may not matter depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

1. If there are non-`.txt` files which might usefully contain the keyword:

> ```
> grep -r KEYWORD *
> ```

This uses the recursive directory search option of `grep`.

2. To search only `.txt` files:

> ```
> find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep KEYWORD {} \;
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep KEYWORD {} +
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> find . -execdir grep KEYWORD {}
> ```

The first runs `grep` for each matching file.  The second runs `grep` much fewer times, accumulating many matched files before invoking `grep.  The third form runs`grep` once in every directory.